# How can I convert gregorian date to julian date in Hive

Tags: apache, hive

I have a table with column name "date". The date is structured as YYYY-MM-DD and i need to convert it to YYYYDDD

I don't think hive has any simple quick way of doing this..
Using hive version 0.13.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the unix timestamp functions. First defining your date format and converting to a unix epoch timestamp, and then converting the unix timestamp into the Julian date format.

```
-- this would give the output of 2016096
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2016-04-05','yyyy-MM-dd'), 'yyyyDDD') from yourTableName
```